# MongoDB, Express, Angular and Mongoose - Custom ObjectID

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have defined custom ObjectID's when inputting data into my MongoDB database as below (selections table):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("99dd0a000a00a0a000aaa00e"),
    "name" : "Draw"
}
```

The issue that my Angular view grabs these from the database as option (selection.selections), shows it in a dropdown, lets you pick it, then on submit it uses the ObjectID for the selection to populate a new table (picks), as below:

```
        "potId" : ObjectId("542ec9ad31f3775756abccdd"),
        "selection" : ObjectId("5469d5101db0d2c602852c08"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("546cd64c51c349965752d359")
```

You can see here that the ObjectID being put in the database for "selection" is nothing like the selection's ObjectID defined above.

Is there an inherit issue with defining custom ObjectID's in JSON files which are being imported? Or is there something wrong on my side (config option?) which is causing this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually doing with the ids. Are you querying your database? If so, how? How do you insert those ids? Oh, and why don't you simply use strings / binary arrays if you don't stick to the convention anyway - that will be irritating, because ObjectIds have a lot of useful properties that your custom ids probably don't have.

Comment: I'm using _id when I define my Object ID in my JSON file. I'll have to double check my imported JSON file and see what happens

Comment: You have JSON data in a *file*? It would really help if you described the actual process, when the inserts, queries and updates happen and what the code is. Or maybe I'm just missing the obvious.

Comment: So i use `mongoimport path/to/json/selection.json` which is just a standard json file e.g. `{"_id":ObjectId("99dd0a000a00a0a000aaa00e"), "name":"Draw"}`. Then I use a dropdown box with angular repeat to show a list of selections which I've imported with the above command (selection in selections). I then use, on submit, submit those selections as `selection: selection._id` to a database collection called "pick". I can paste exact code tomorrow but that's the gist of it. When I do the submit the "pick" database is showing `selection: selection._id` as a random that I don't use (code above)

Comment: @Gary, that's a design issue, better avoid using auto generated '_id', add new fields in documents, that would be the best.